# MySQL: select tuples until a column's summing up reaches a threshold

Tags: mysql

I have this simple table:

```
Name    percentage  
John        0.0069
Anna        0.0049
Martin      0.0047
George      0.0047
Calvin      0.0044
Andrew      0.0044
```

The idea is: "select the first X elements which percentages sum up to 0.51".

Could it be possible in a MySQL query to select tuples until the summing up of the percentages reaches a threshold?

Theyre already in order, and I want the element that reaches and passes the threshold as well

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Of course, but remember that rows in a table have no inherent order so you'd need to define one in some way - like (as appears to be the case here) from largest to smallest.

Comment: Okay what happens if you have more than one person with the same name? Need some sort of ordering principle. Descending order of percentage for instance. Also do you want the record that takes you over the threshold or not.

Comment: 1. They are all unique names. 2. Order is descending so I can have the 'most relevant' ones. 3. Yes, I want the record that takes me over the threshold. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM simple x 
  JOIN simple y 
    ON y.percentage > x.percentage 
    OR (y.percentage = x.percentage AND y.name >= x.name) 
 GROUP 
    BY x.name 
HAVING SUM(y.percentage) < 0.02;
```

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Do I have to duplicate the table? Why y.name >= x.name? And SUM(y.percentage) < 0.02?

Comment: A) No. It's not a 'duplicate'. It's an 'instance'. B) In the absence of other criteria, you'll need some mechanism for dealing with ties. Otherwise this won't work. C) You said you wanted a threshold, so I gave you one - except my idea takes you *to* the threshold. You'll need to adapt it a little to get *over* the threshold.